# Etymology and meaning of "Lotterleben"

Tags: meaning

A German friend of mine used the term "Lotterleben" to describe to me someone as a "free spirit", although the dictionary translate the term as "dissolute lifestyle" which have a string negative meaning. I want to more of the usage of this term and it's etymology if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Lotterleben* definitely has a negative connotation and is used for a dissolute lifestyle (as you said). Depending on the views of the user of the word, this may include promiscuity, wasting the money of others (usually one’s parents), drugs, criminal activities, laziness, carelessness about one’s own concerns, untidiness etc. (basically everything associated with clichéic students).

The origin should be from or the same as [Lotterbett](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Lotterbett), which describes a bed that is in an rickety, untidy or otherwise low-quality state, or *lotterig* which is an adjective describing untidiness, bad shape etc. in general. The part *lotter* itself is derived from Old German *lotar,* meaning flabby, loose, void, frivolous (see [here](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Lotterbett)).

Comment: Für Spießer gebe ich Dir recht, aber da nicht jedermann ein Spießer ist, etwa Prostituierte, Drogenabhängige, Kriminelle und clicheeartige Studenten nicht, kann von "definitely" kaum gesprochen werden. Es ist Deine persönliche Wertung, vielleicht.

Comment: Nur weil es Menschen gibt, die den Kritikpunkt eines abwertenden Begriffs nicht mehr als abwertend ansehen, wird der Begriff nicht automatisch zum [Geusenwort](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geusenwort). Ich kann mir z. B. nicht vorstellen, dass sich selbst jemand als *Vollidiot* bezeichnen würde, auch wenn er an seiner Dummheit nichts Schlimmes sieht. Du kannst mir aber gerne Beispiele entgegenhalten, in denen *Lotterleben* nicht abwertend (und auch nicht ironisch) genutzt wird. Und nebenbei: Mit meiner persönlichen Meinung hat mein Beitrag nichts zu tun.

Comment: Wrzprmft is absolutely right - one should note, however, that in certain contexts, this could be used ironically, implying a certain level of admiration.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Es geht nicht um Geusenworte sondern darum, dass die Schimpfwörter einer vergangenen Epoche heute nicht jedem mehr als Schimpfwort taugen.

Comment: @user unknown: Das ist sicher richtig, aber wenn jemandem ein Wort weder als Schimpfwort noch als Geusenwort taugt, dann nutzt er es schlichtweg gar nicht mehr. Das ändert aber nichts am abwertenden Charakter des Wortes: Wer es nutzt, nutzt es abwertend. Nebenbei braucht man im vorliegenden Fall ja gar nicht alle genannten Aspekte als negativ empfinden. Fast jeder Mensch hat eine Grenze, unterhalb derer er z. B. Faulheit oder Unordentlichkeit als negativ empfindet und kann seinen Unmut mittels des Begriffs *Lotterleben* ausdrücken.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Schön, dass Du für fast alle Menschen sprechen kannst - ich kann das nicht. Aber ich kann für mich sprechen, und auf mich wirkt "Lotterleben" wie ein Begriff aus dem Biedermeier, als man ein Lotterleben führte, wenn man Sonntags nicht zur Kirche ging. Daran finde ich gar nichts negativ. Eine Unordnung die pathologisch wird betrachtet man heute eben eher als Symptom und verurteilt den Betroffenen nicht. Die Neigung andere abzuwerten halte ich für ein größeres Problem und für antiintellektuell.

Comment: @ user unknown: Dir ist schon klar, dass es deutliche Unterschiede zwischen »als negativ empfinden«, »abwerten«, »die zugehörige Person verurteilen« und »die zugehörige Person abwerten« gibt, oder? Und wenn ich Deiner Logik folge, gibt es überhaupt keine abwertenden Begriffe mehr, insbesondere keine, die aus der Mode gekommen sind. Mal ein paar Beispielbegriffe zum Nachdenken: Bastard, Arschficker, gottverlassen, unsittlich, Schwuchtel, Wichser.

Comment: @userunknown Du scheinst dich angegriffen zu fühlen – wieso? Führst du etwa ein Lotterleben? `: – D` Jedenfalls ist es absolut klar, dass *Lotterleben* eine negative Konnotation hat. Ich habe es nie positiv oder neutral verwendet gesehen, höchstens eben ironisch. *Spießer* ist übrigens auch negativ konnotiert, oder würdest du da sagen „Für Studenten vielleicht schon. Für CDU-Wähler aber …“?

Answer (score 4):

#### [Lotter](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Lotter)

The term *"Lotter"* is still listed in Duden as a regionally used collquial German word for a *tramp* or *vagabond*. It is not used very often any more, but this was different as we can see from entries and quotes in the [Grimm's Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GL06962):

> **LOTTER** das wort bezeichnet bei seinem frühesten vorkommen als ags. loddere, schlechthin einen zerlumpten kerl [...] im mhd. und noch später geht loter, lotter, loder vornehmlich auf den herumziehenden gaukler und spaszmacher, possenreiszer um geld, mit schimpflichem nebensinne.

This indicates that there always was a negative connotation to *"Lotter"* which is also adherent to *"Lotterleben"* describing a dissipated, and somewhat disordered life style similar to that of a vagabond, or *"Lotterbett"* for a likewise bacchanal usage of a bed.

Note that regionally we may still find the expression *"die Lotter"*, *"die Lotterbank"* for a lounge seated next to a stove used for casual hanging out.

According to Grimm the etymology of the Old High German **lotar** may share an common etymology with Old English **loddere** which became *"to loiter"* in modern English.

Comment: So don't name your son 'Lothar' ;)